# Can't understand RxJS filter syntax

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm trying to understand an app in an Ionic/Angular project. At one point there is a filter expression:

```
private userId$ = this.authService.currentUserAuth$.pipe(
    filter(user => !!user),
    map((user) => user.uid)
  );
```

`authservice` is an `AngularFireAuth` type and `user` is a `firebase.user` type. What I can't understand is the filter expression `user => !!user`. I have found that `!!` will coerce the variable into being a boolean, but that doesn't make any sense to me in the context.  Can anybody help?

Comment: It's making sure the user exists. All nulls and undefineds (and empty strings, 0s, etc) will be excluded.

Comment: That's basic JS, nothing to do with Angular, Ionic, TypeScript or RxJS.

Comment: It's exactly the same syntax as in `Array.filter()`, a lambda-function that returns a boolean value. You maybe need some more experience with basic JS before diving into RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` accepts a predicate function which will return a boolean.  `user => !!user` in any javascript context is saying "given an argument `user` (which is the value going down your rxjs `pipe`), is that a truthy type?" where "truthy" means something that is not `undefined`, `null`, `false`, `0` (of any variety), `NaN`, or an empty string.

If `user` is any of those values (probably `null` or `undefined` from your auth service) it will not execute the next step in the chain, your case trying to extract `uuid` in the `map`

Comment: Thank you, it's not obvious, and searching on Google did not result in any answer - probably have to ask the question in exactly the right way to get an answer.  Some of these things are like magical incantations!